# Invalidation on auto-invalidation but retained timer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

By saying

```
_requestTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(updateSystems)
                                                userInfo:nil 
                                                  repeats:NO] retain];
```

I retain an NSTimer that would, without retain, auto-invalidate (since repeats is set to NO).

I later say

```
[_requestTimer invalidate];
```

While this invalidates the timer, as it would do automatically without retain, I keep thinking what happens to the auto-invalidation? 
Does `[_requestTimer invalidate];` release my retained reference and as well as the reference that would automatically release? Or do I have a memory leak?
According to the profiler, I get a leak, but I don't know if it's my retain, the auto-retain or the profiler not catching up (which would be highly unlikely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No invalidate does not release you timer, you also do not need to retain your NSTimer if you do not need to deal with it after creation, for example if you do not want to stop it from firing, the NSTimer is retained somewhere within the NSRunLoop which is responsable for fire ring your timer.

Comment: I do need to handle it after creation. The other option would be to set REPEATS:YES and the forget about retaining it, and then only invalidate later, but that feels strange since I don't want it to repeat.

Comment: Well yes if you want to hold onto it then you will have to retain and the release it, releasing without invalidating will not stop NSTimer from firing since all you ave done is released your hold on it and not NSTimers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set _requestTimer to nil in your updateSystems method and not do the retain, then by testing _requestTimer == nil you know if your timer has fired (and of course any messages sent to nil are ignored anyway so you win....)